# How to get initial value of datePicker Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, uidatepicker

I want to get initial value of timePicker, value changes when I am just scrolling time. Please watch photos it will be more clear to understand what I want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj5GA.jpg

```
@IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    datePickerLb.text = strDate
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to update the label inside your `viewDidLoad` method. I would move the date formatter declaration out of that method to avoid creating a new one every time the value changes. Note that you should use `timeStyle` or `dateFormat` but not both. When displaying dates to the end user you should always respect the devices locale and settings so you should choose `timeStyle` in this case:

---

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
    return dateFormatter
}()
```

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // your code

    // you can update the label here
    // datePickerLb.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
    // or manually send the valueChanged action to force the update at view did load
    datePicker.sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
}
```

---

```
@IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    datePickerLb.text = dateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer by @Leo is practical. One thing to add is that if you wanted the date updated while picker it is rolling then, unfortunately, it is impossible with `UIDatePicker` itself. This is because `UIDatePicker` is not a subclass of `UIPickerView` and it manages a UIPickerView internally. The the solution here might be use a custom `UIPickerView`. Then for that UIPickerView you can implement it's delegate method like this:

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

```
switch component {
case 0:
    currentTime.hours = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    return "\(row) Hour"
case 1:
    currentTime.minutes = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
    return "\(row) Minute"
case 2:
    currentTime.seconds = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)
    return "\(row) Second"
default:
    return ""
```

}

}

`currentTime` var should, for example, have a `didSet` to update some view elements when it changes.